# Multiple chance to proc (freeze, stun etc.) on a single weapon

Tags: diablo-iii

I was trying to find some weapons that have both chance to freeze and chance to stun on the AH, and to my surprise I could not find a single item that had two different procs (freeze, stun, knockback, fear, immobilize etc.) Of course, it could very well just be a case of such weapons having poor damage and not being sold on AH.

Is it possible for the D3 loot roll to generate items with multiple proc types?

Comment: I know it is possible for certain affixes to be mutually exclusive, so it's possible that this isn't possible.

Comment: As @MatthewScharley said - in addition it's probably too early in the game's life to completely rule it out not being a possibility. If it is a possibility at all though it will be one of those 1 in 1 billion possibilities as the combination of procs has the potential to be seriously overpowered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible under the current 1.03 rare/magic mechanics.
Only on legendary/sets is it possible.